# How to change Android ImageButton's Bitmap to another bitmap stored in R.Layout

Tags: java, android, image, imagebutton

I have set an Android ImageButton's Bitmap to a jpeg from the net via a HTTPUrlConnection and want to change it when the user clicks it. I set up a View.onClickListener which gets triggered correctly but the code it fires doesnt seem to chaneg the image on the button.

I fire ImageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1); however im thinking maybe the background is behind the Bitmap already set (as the name suggests). What should i be doing to set R.darwable.image1?

Current code;

```
View.OnClickListener handlerImgBtnCatCelebrities1 = new View.OnClickListener() 
{
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
        ImageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);  
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about, [setImageResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)?

Don't get confused by the fact that this method refers to the `ImageView` class, because an `ImageButton` is actually an `ImageView` or in other words: the `ImageButton` class extends the `ImageView` class.

[ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Rolf

Comment: thanks Rolf, what should i do to chaneg the imagebuttons imageView to my r.layout.image1?

Comment: Sorry didnt see your 1st line, that worked, thanks a mil Rolf